# How to delete duplicate record where PK is uniqueidentifier field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to know the way we can remove duplicate records where PK is uniqueidentifier.
I have to delete records on the basis of duplicate values in a set of fields.we can use option to get temptable using Row_Number() and except row number one we can delete rest or the records.
But I wanted to build one liner query. Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you have duplicate records with a unique PK? Is there some other criteria to classify it as 'duplicate'?

Comment: In my case duplicate records are identified by "duplicate values in a set of fields". For e.g: if i have table with id,a,b,c,d fields than if a,b and d fields have same values in two records,these will be treated as duplicate records.

Comment: We need to see a table structure to help you further.

Comment: So if `a`, `b` and `d` match, do you care which value of `c` is kept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CTE to do this, without seeing your table structure here is the basic SQL

```
;with cte as
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by yourfields order by yourfields) rn
    from yourTable
)
delete
from cte
where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table t using table ta where ta.dup_field=t.dup_field and t.pk >ta.pk
;
```

Comment: You are referencing `tu` which you don't define in the query, and should probably have at least a sentence explaining how the query works.